# sails.js less livereload with grunt watch not working

Tags: less, sails.js, grunt-contrib-watch

I got my less files compiled in css perfectly by grunt and I see result in **.tmp/public/styles**
So now **livereload** with **grunt-contrib-watch** should be made naturally in sails generated project ?
Or do I have to make a special configuration ?

I found that in **tasks/pipeline.js** file but not sure of what to do.

```
// CSS files to inject in order
//
// (if you're using LESS with the built-in default config, you'll want
//  to change `assets/styles/importer.less` instead.)
var cssFilesToInject = [
  'styles/**/*.css'
];
```

I saw in the file **tasks/README.md** :

```
###### `sails lift`

Runs the `default` task (`tasks/register/default.js`).
```

And in the file **default.js** we got :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['compileAssets', 'linkAssets',  'watch']);
};
```

But **watch.js** file is missing in the folder...
What should it be ?

Answer (score 0):

Watch does only looking for files that have changed and execute less, sass, injection and so on - but it doesn't make a reload.

You can add this in `task/config/watch.js`