# Get livereload to work with Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, grunt-contrib-watch, livereload, browser-sync, grunt-contrib-connect

I am new to both Sails and grunt so I might be missing the obvious.
I am **trying to automatically refresh my sails app in the browser whenever files change**.

I start the app with `sails lift` and it runs on the default port `1337`.

I tried adding `options: {livereload:true}` to my `grunt-contrib-watch` configuration but as far as I understand I need to somehow inject the livereload JavaScript into my page?

I tried to use `grunt-contrib-connect` with the `livereload` option to inject the JavaScript but it seems to just start another server. When I navigate to the started server (`localhost:8000`) I just see the folder structure. The livereload JavaScript is injected however.

I want to avoid the livereload Chrome Plugin if possible.

What's the best way to inject the livereload JavaScript into my Sails app? Or should I just use another tool like Browsersync?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add livereload option to *tasks/config/watch.js*

```js
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

     grunt.config.set('watch', {
        api: {

            // API files to watch:
            files: ['api/**/*', '!**/node_modules/**']
        },
        assets: {

            // Assets to watch:
            files: ['assets/**/*', 'tasks/pipeline.js', '!**/node_modules/**'],

            // When assets are changed:
            tasks: ['syncAssets' , 'linkAssets']
        },
        // ADD THIS 
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

2. Add livereload script to your layout, somewhere at the end before `</body>` tag, by default to *views/layout.ejs*:

```html
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Except of localhost you can use IP or DNS name of server

**This will refresh page if a file is changed in *api* or *assets* folder.**

By default Ggrunt-contrib-watch uses **35729** port. You can point other port like `livereload: 8000`

- [Similar question, but not so detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336190/sails-js-less-livereload-with-grunt-watch-not-working)
- [Ggrunt-contrib-watch docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload)

**EDIT:**
Well, I do not really know if this is totally correct, but looks like you can override layout settings in `config/env/development.js`. Add something like:

```js
module.exports = {
    views: {
        layout: 'dev'
    }
}
```

Then you can create separate layout file `views/dev.ejs` where you can add livereload script and other development params. Also you can add `livereload` key in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you also have a suggestion how to dynamically inject the script tag (instead of just adding it to layout)? Because I don't want to include it in production mode.

Comment: @PhilippBaschke I added some info to the answer, did not test that

Comment: Both your suggestions work! :) And with the `views/dev.ejs` , the livereload script does not show up when I `sails lift --prod`. I don't like the duplication of the layout though and I still feel like it should be possible via `devJs` in `tasks/config/sails-linker.js` somehow. But **it works, so thank you very much! :)**

Comment: @PhilippBaschke I think the best option is to add an environment test inside layout.ejs like this :

`<% if(sails.config.environment == 'development' ){ %>
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
<% } %>`

Comment: @codeKonami Well that was easy. Thank you very much for your tip! :)

Comment: While this does cause livereload to work, I noticed there will sometimes be a looping reload especially when working with html or css assets. What I did was change the "tasks" to ["build"] instead of ["syncAssets",..etc.]. Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

After lost some time trying do this with sails/grunt, i install the livereload browser plugin (http://livereload.com/extensions/) for .html, js and css and the package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-autoreload) for the models and controllers.

Works like a charm.